# ifconfig and after not working after update Magento from 2.1.2 to 2.2.7

Tags: php, magento2

I updated the magento from version 2.1.2 to 2.2.7.

When i want to go to the product page then i see this error:

```
    Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'before': The attribute 'before' is not allowed.
    Line: 1508

    Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed.
    Line: 1624
```

I have found the information that it is no longer allowed and should be removed but  I'm not sure if I understand correctly.

Example i have a block like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="rewards" frontName="rewards">
            <module name="Mirasvit_Rewards" before="Magento_Adminhtml"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Do I have to remove the tag before and whether it should look like this:

```
<module name="Mirasvit_Rewards"/>
```

Similarly for ifconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.actions.toolbar">
            <block ifconfig="pdfpro/general/enabled" class="Vnecoms\PdfPro\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\PrintButton" as="pdfpro_print_button"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I will be grateful for any help!